# I got This Error While Implementing Push Notification using REST API::The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I got an error While use this code. I give a proper credentials for Urban Airship.

```
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/");
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UrbanAirShip UserLogin, MasterKey);

            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";

            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            //WRITE JSON DATA TO VARIABLE D
            string postData = "{\"aps\": {\"badge\": 1, \"alert\": \"Hello from Urban Airship!\"}, \"device_tokens\": [\"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"]}";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            // Get the request stream.
            using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                // Write the data to the request stream.
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }

            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            //Error "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                {
                    // Read the content.
                    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    // Display the content.
                    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

                    response.Close();

                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";``

        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array. 
        string postData = "{\"aps\": {\"badge\": 1, \"alert\": \"Hello from Urban Airship!\"},                  \"device_tokens\": [\"Device_Token\"]}";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        //Do a http basic authentication somehow
        string username = "xxxx";  //App Key From Urban Airship
        string password = "xxxxx"; //Master Secret Key From Urban Airship
        string usernamePassword = username + ":" + password;
        CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
        mycache.Add(new Uri("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/"), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));
        request.Credentials = mycache;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)));

        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```